# Как поместить кнопку со списком напротив каждой ячейки слева с помощью цикла?

Tags: php, html

В данной строчке, мы вытаскиваем список продуктов из БД, и каждый продукт помещаем в отдельную ячейку слева.

```
<?php foreach($title as $products){echo "<tr><td>$products</td></tr>";}?>
```

В этой строчке по моим представления из цикла тоже должен вытаскиваться список продуктов, и помещаться в ячейки напротив, НО уже в списке select, подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить?

```
<?php foreach($title as $products){echo "<option>$products</option>";}?>
```

Как должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный код:

```
<table border="1"> 
    <tr>
    <td>Номенклатура 1</td>
    <td>Номенклатура 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach($title as $products){echo "<option>$products</option>";}?>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <select>
        <?php foreach($showproductsdb as $db){ echo "<option>$db->productsiiko</option>";} ?>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: <tr> - создает новую строку
<td> - создает столбец в этой строке. Если Вы хотите создать таблицу с 2мя столбцами, то то прописывайте после каждого <tr> по 2 <td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
<table border="1"> 
    <tr>
    <td>Номенклатура 1</td>
    <td>Номенклатура 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select id="product">
        <?php foreach($title as $products){echo "<option>$products</option>";}?>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
      <select>
        <?php foreach($showproductsdb as $db){ echo "<option>$db->productsiiko</option>";} ?>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```